# How to Connect a DataBase and GUI in visual studio using grid to be able to search

Tags: c#, mysql, sql, user-interface

So i am making a database and gui i have a gridpane so when you search something in the textbox the gridpane will pop up the information but i don't really know how to i keep getting errors in my code when i try making it work.

When i don't run the gui i dont see any errors but when i do i see this..

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vPPgk.png)

This is the error i am getting...

Comment: That is a very general Exception and a number of things could cause it. Post the relevant code (at least the query that is hidden by the error message), and click on the "View Detail..." link so that you can see the specifics of the error. Also don't post a picture of the error, **write** the error out with the relevant code.

Comment: In order to make this question helpful for others, you should maybe add some code snippets and the error message. By providing a screenshot, this problem will not be visible to any search engine. Please consider to add this information.

Comment: Please provide sql select statement

Answer (score 0):

actually your sql query is not correct. make sure that you write it correctly..